# Alternatives to Sunbird?

Tags: software-recommendation, calendar, alternative, webdav

I have an ical file on my webserver, shared via webdav... Since Sunbird isn't supported anymore, what are the alternatives, aside from Thunderbird+Lightning (which I'd like to avoid, since I use another mail program) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Evolution](http://projects.gnome.org/evolution/), it was the default mail / calendar application before 11.10, and I'm still using it at work.

It support web calendars, and if you need, also Google Calendar. For example I upload my ICS file to my web space, I configured that ICS on Google Calendar, so I can see in Evolution and if I am not at my computer also with Google web interface.

It also as calendar events integration with the datetime indicator (the clock on right-top).

Click here to install: http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/evolution

Comment: I tried installing Evolution but it has a lot of dependencies that I'm missing :( (I'm using Lubuntu) Thanks for your help though :)

Comment: Oh in fact Evolution is a part of the Gnome suite, maybe you are right, is not good integrated in other window managers.